# Cofibration necessarily has closed image?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know how to show that if $i: A \to X$ is a cofibration, then $i$ is injective, and in fact a homeomorphism onto its image. My question is, must the image necessarily be closed? I've tried constructing counterexamples but to no avail, which leads me to believe the answer to my question is yes...

Is there something very simple I'm missing?

EDIT: We are working with Hausdorff spaces here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of Hausdorff spaces or compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces, every cofibration is a closed inclusion. However, it is not true in full generality, which is exemplified by the following example:

Take a one point space and include it in a two point space with the trivial topology. This is a cofibration, but the point is not closed.

Every cofibration is injective and if the image is closed, it is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Do you know an example of a cofibration which is not an embedding?

Comment: I spent the last minutes trying to construct such an example, but was not successful so far.

Comment: I admit this was a loaded question. Actually every cofibration is an embedding.