# Showing that a Cofibration has closed image

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am learning cofibrations and have seen the answer here: [Cofibration necessarily has closed image?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363377/cofibration-necessarily-has-closed-image).  I have been able to show that if $i: A \to X$ is a cofibration then it is an embedding. If in the case that $X,A$ is Hausdorff, I now want to show that $i(A)$ is closed. I have shown that $i$ is injective and that it is a homeomorphism onto its image. I was thinking that this would imply that $i(A)$ is closed since $A $ is closed in the subspace topology. But  I think this is wrong since I never use the Hausdorff condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, each cofibration is an embedding (i.e. we have a homeomorphism $i' : A \to i(A)$, where $i(A)$ has the subspace topology inherited from $X$). However, in general $i(A)$ is not closed in $X$ as shown by the example in the above link.

Let us show that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A' = i(A)$ is closed. We know that there exists a retraction $r : X \times [0,1] \to X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1]$. Then $r(\overline{A'} \times \{ 1\}) = r(\overline{A' \times \{ 1\}}^{X \times [0,1]}) \subset \overline{r(A' \times \{ 1\})}^{X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1]} = \overline{A' \times \{ 1\}}^{X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1]} = A' \times \{ 1\}$ which means that for $x \in \overline{A'}$ we can write $r(x,1) = (\rho(x),1)$ with a continuous map $\rho : \overline{A'} \to \overline{A'}$ such that $\rho(x) = x$ for $x \in A'$ and $\rho(\overline{A'}) = A'$. The identity on $\overline{A'}$ and $\rho$ agree on $A'$. Since $\overline{A'}$ is Hausdorff, we conclude $\rho = id$. This implies $\overline{A'} = id(\overline{A'}) =  \rho(\overline{A'}) = A'$.

Comment: Hmm I'm having trouble with the last part, since $\overline{A}'$ is Hausdorff, the identity must agree with the retract. Could you give me a hint on that part?

Comment: The set of points where two maps $f, g : Y \to Z$ to a Hausdorff space $Z$ agree is closed in $Y$. Apply this to $id_{\overline{A'}}$ and the retraction $\rho$. They agree on $A'$ and hence on $\overline{A'}$.

Comment: How do we know $\overline{A'\times\{1\}}=A'\times\{1\}$?

Comment: Let $(x,t)$ belong to the closure of $A' \times \{ 1 \}$ in $X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1]$. This means that any open neighborhood $U \subset X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1]$ of $(x,t)$  intersects  $A' \times \{ 1 \}$. For $(x,t)$ with $t < 1$ we see that $X \times \{ 0 \} \cup A' \times [0,1)$  is an open neighborhood not intersecting   $A' \times \{ 1 \}$. This shows that we must have $t = 1$. But then automatically $x \in A'$.

Comment: Small improvement is possible. Spanier proves directly from definition that if $i:A\to X$ is a cofibration, then there is a retracting function $r: X \times [0,1] \to X \times \{ 0 \} \cup_i A \times [0,1].$ It does not break essential arguments, but $X \times \{ 0 \} \cup_i A \times [0,1]$ as factor space may not inherit topology from $X \times I$ in general.